# wget download regex pattern files from remote URL

Tags: linux, regular-expression, wget, download

I want to download all `*httpd*` RPM file from remote CentOS mirror and I am trying he following command but it doesn't seem to work

`[root@yum foo]# wget -r --no-parent -A "*httpd*" https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/`

I see that it created a directory structure, but there are no files in the directories.

```
[root@yum foo]# ls
mirrors.edge.kernel.org
```

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web site you're trying to do this on has a `robots.txt` file that includes

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

When in recursive mode, `wget` obeys this file, and so refuses to do recursive copies.

Comment: any solution here or any other tool like `curl` ?

Comment: Use a different mirror that doesn't have a `robots.txt` ?  eg `wget -r --no-parent -A "*httpd*" https://mirrors.xmission.com/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/
` works as expected

Comment: if the robots file is indeed the problem, you may also use `-e robots=off` to ignore the robots file